# Outputting hex values in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, shellcode

I am writing shellcode exploits with python3. However, when I try and output some hex bytes. e.g. using the line - `python3 -c 'print("\x8c")' | xxd`

The value in `xxd` is `c28c`, rather than the expected `8c`

This issue does not occur in python2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue arises because Python 3 handles strings as Unicode, and `print` expects Unicode to encode some output for your terminal. Try the following to bypass this:

```
python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x8c')" | xxd
```

Comment: That worked!, so just to understand further, the addition of `2c` happens when `print()` tries to convert the unicode string to byte form?